# Subprocess output not spliting

Tags: python, subprocess

I trying to capture to output of a subprocess task but it won't split by '\n'.

This is the code by now:

```
import subprocess

a = subprocess.run('ipconfig', capture_output=True, text=True)

b = []

for line in a.stdout:
    print(line.split('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.stdout` is a string; if you use a string in a `for` loop, you are iterating over its characters. Therefore, you are splitting each character on `\n`. Instead, you can simply use the following line to convert the `stdout` of `ipconfig` to a list of lines:

```
lines = a.stdout.split('\n')
```